# How to register IUserAuthRepository when the OrmLiteConnectionFactory is using Named Connections

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Here is the appHost configuration code:

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = PostgreSQLDialectProvider.Instance;

var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory();
dbFactory.RegisterConnection("NamedKeyConnOne", new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("ConnOne"))
{
    ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
});
dbFactory.RegisterConnection("NamedKeyConnTwo", new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("ConnTwo")
{
    ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
});
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);
```

and here is the authentication portion:

```
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>())); //Authentication and authorization
container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
```

So my question is "How do you go about passing the correct IDbConnectionFactory when there is no default connection string?"

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inject a named `IDbConnection` connection but you can resolve it from the `IDbConnectionFactory` which you can access from your services like:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

    public object Any(Request request)
    {
        using (var db = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection("NamedKeyConnOne"))
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the IUserAuthRepository?, that's the part I'm not clear on. Each tenant needs it's own auth tables.

Comment: @StephenPatten The [OrmLiteAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs) is also injected with an `IDbConnectionFactory` but doesn't support named connections, you would need to use a custom modified version of it instead.